# How to set a Timer based on a user choice?

Tags: c#

I am working on a small program and, everything works fine. Instead of having a hard coded `timer` though, I'd like to change the `timers` `interval` from the form from a `listbox` or a `numericupdownbox`, `combobox` or something along those lines.

So instead of it being a hard coded 3000MS like it is I wanted to be able to change it on the `form` from a small menu with 1000-10000 milliseconds.

The thing is, I am not sure how to tell the `timer` to use an interval specified in a optional box.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend using a thread for the timer function (sleep as interval), should be easier to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use a control that allows for a non-numeric input such as  a `TextBox` ensure you validate that the input is in fact a number. Better to trap errors in the first place than deal with exceptions later.

```
private void SetIntervalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int interval = 0;
    bool success = Int32.TryParse(intervalTextBox.Text, out interval);

    if(success)
    {
        operationTimer.Interval = interval;
    }
}
```

You can omit the checking above if you're using a `NumericUpDown` control as it only allows a numeric value.

```
private void SetIntervalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    operationTimer.Interval = (int) numericUpDown1.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `interval` of a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) to a value you like in the change event your your `combobox`.

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
   aTimer.Interval = double.Parse(ComboBox1.SelectedValue);
}
```

You should use [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) if you can not ensure valid data for setting the interval. If the value is being taken from a `combobox` and its read-only then there is no need for `TryParse`.

Comment: If values is being take from combo and its ready only then there is no need for TryParse, any how I have added your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
myTimer.Interval  = (int) myTextbox.Text;
```

You can put this in textchanged event if you want it fired every time you change the textbox value.

Comment: As was mentioned above though, what happens to this if an end-user enters a `string`?  With this example you would get an `InvalidCastException`.